¿Como hago para cambiar el modo de entrega y la fecha de una linea de carrito a traves de codigo ts c# en commerceruntime retail server pos Microsoft?
Estoy intentando cambiar el modo de entrega y la fecha de envio de una linea de carrito en POS, tengo que entregar un desarrollo el cual por cada linea de carrito puedo asignarle una direccion modos de envio distintos etc...
Estoy usando retail server POS dynamics 365 commerce, alguien podria ayudarme como puedo hacer que el modo de envio y la fecha de envio se me guarden en el carrito, para poder continuar con la transaccion, en el siguiente codigo como pueden ver las lineas que estan seleccionadas se les cambia la fecha y el modo de envio que llegan a esta funcion como parametros, luego de ello preparo el request que me va a enviar esas lineas del carrito actualizadas
codigo del frontend Typescript
public async updateCartLineDeliveryDate(date: Date, deliveryMode): Promise<void> {
    try {
        this.selectedDeliveryDate = date; // Almacenar la fecha seleccionada
        const cart = await this.getCartInformation2();
        console.log("***********Data - PRE************ ", cart);
        for (let cartLine of cart.result.CartLines) {
            if (this.selectedLineIds().includes(cartLine.LineId)) {
                cartLine.RequestedDeliveryDate = date;
                cartLine.DeliveryMode = deliveryMode
            }
        }

        const updateCartLineDate = cart.result.CartLines
            .filter(cartLine => this.selectedLineIds().includes(cartLine.LineId))
            .map(cartLine => ({
                CartId: cart.result.Id,
                CartLines: [{
                    LineId: cartLine.LineId,
                    ...cartLine,
                    DeliveryMode: cartLine.DeliveryMode,
                    RequestedDeliveryDate: cartLine.RequestedDeliveryDate,
                    ShippingAddress: cartLine.ShippingAddress,
                }],
                CalculationMode: null,
                CartVersion: null,
                ExtensionProperties: []
            }));

        const updateCartLineDeliveryDate = new Messages.StoreOperations.UpdateLinesRequest(cart.result.Id, updateCartLineDate);
        const response = await this.context.runtime.executeAsync(updateCartLineDeliveryDate);

        if (response.canceled) {
            console.error("UpdateCartLineDateDelivery request was canceled.");
        } else {
            console.log("Cart lines updated successfully.");
        }

        await this.getCartInformation();
     
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

Backend
Controller
[HttpPost]
[Authorization(CommerceRoles.Employee, CommerceRoles.Device, CommerceRoles.Anonymous, CommerceRoles.BusinessPartnerEmployee)]
public async Task<Cart> UpdateLines(IEndpointContext context, string cartId, IEnumerable<UpdateCartLineAddress> updateCartLineAddress)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSDataRequest(cartId, updateCartLineAddress);
        var response = await context.ExecuteAsync<UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSDataResponse>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response.Cart;
    }
    catch (CommerceException ex)
    {
        var error = ($"CommerceException occurred: {ex.Message}");
        error = ($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        throw;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = $"Unexpected error in {nameof(UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSController)}: {ex.Message}";
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        Console.WriteLine($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
        throw new CommerceException(nameof(UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSController), ex, errorMessage);
    }
}

requestHandler
using Microsoft.Dynamics.Commerce.Runtime.DataModel;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.Commerce.Runtime.Messages;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.Commerce.Runtime.Services.Messages;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.Commerce.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TUGCollectionTransportPOS.CommerceRuntime.Messages.UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESS;
using TUGCollectionTransportPOS.CommerceRuntime.Controllers.UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESS;

namespace TUGCollectionTransportPOS.CommerceRuntime.RequestHandlers.UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESS
{
    public class UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSRequestHandler : SingleAsyncRequestHandler<UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSDataRequest>
    {
        protected override async Task<Response> Process(UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSDataRequest request)
        {
            var originalCart = await GetCart(request.CartId, request.RequestContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
            IList<CartLine> updatedCartLines = new List<CartLine>();

            foreach (var address in request.UpdateCartLinesAddress)
            {
                // Iterar sobre cada línea del carrito en la dirección proporcionada
                foreach (var cartLineAddress in address.CartLines)
                {
                    // Encuentra la línea del carrito que corresponde a la dirección proporcionada
                    var cartLine = originalCart.CartLines.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.LineId == cartLineAddress.LineId);

                    if (cartLine != null)
                    {
                        // Actualizar la dirección de entrega en la línea del carrito
                        cartLine.ShippingAddress = cartLineAddress.ShippingAddress;
                        // Agregar la línea del carrito actualizada a la lista
                        updatedCartLines.Add(cartLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (updatedCartLines.Any())
            {
                try
                {
                    var updateCartRequest = new SaveCartLinesRequest(originalCart, updatedCartLines, TransactionOperationType.Update, CalculationModes.None);
                    var updatedCartResponse = await request.RequestContext.ExecuteAsync<SaveCartLinesResponse>(updateCartRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Retornar el carrito actualizado en la respuesta
                    return new UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSDataResponse(updatedCartResponse.Cart);

                }
                catch (CommerceException ex)
                {
                    var error = ($"CommerceException occurred: {ex.Message}");
                    error = ($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
                    throw;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorMessage = $"Unexpected error in {nameof(UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSController)}: {ex.Message}";
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
                    throw new CommerceException(nameof(UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSController), ex, errorMessage);
                }


               
            }

            return new UPDATECARTLINEDELIVERYADDRESSDataResponse(originalCart);
        }

        private static async Task<Cart> GetCart(string cartId, RequestContext context)
        {
            var getCartServiceRequest = new GetCartServiceRequest(new CartSearchCriteria(cartId), QueryResultSettings.SingleRecord);
            var cartResponse = await context.ExecuteAsync<GetCartServiceResponse>(getCartServiceRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return cartResponse.Carts.Single();
        }
    }
}


se supone que el me actualiza el deliveryMode y el requestedDeliveryDate, pero al llamar de nuevo al carrito se me pierde esa informacion, y no puedo terminar la transaccion en POS
Esperaba que al cambiar el modo de envio y fecha de entrega me dejara continuar la transaccion
